# Mapbox How to show marker on current location?

Tags: javascript, maps, mapbox

I want to build a page which shows users current location.
Feature I want to build is that user can select any place on the map and script will calculate the distance between his location and clicked location.

What have been achieved: the web site shows location and I user can click to put second marker.

Problem: the first marker should be appearing on users current location.

Code which already have:
[JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ejaemcnd/)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>Distance between two markers</title>
<meta name='viewport' content='initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no' />
<script src='https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/v2.4.0/mapbox.js'></script>
<link href='https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/v2.4.0/mapbox.css' rel='stylesheet' />
<style>
 body { margin:0; padding:0; }
  #map { position:absolute; top:0; bottom:0; width:100%; }
</style>
</head>
<body>


<style>
pre.ui-distance {
  position:absolute;
  bottom:10px;
  left:10px;
  padding:5px 10px;
  background:rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
  color:#fff;
  font-size:11px;
  line-height:18px;
  border-radius:3px;
  }
  .ui-button {
  background:#3887BE;
  color:#FFF;
  display:block;
  position:absolute;
  top:50%;left:50%;
  width:160px;
  margin:-20px 0 0 -80px;
  z-index:100;
  text-align:center;
  padding:10px;
  border:1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
  border-radius:3px;
  }
  .ui-button:hover {
    background:#3074a4;
    color:#fff;
    }
</style>
<div id='map'></div>
<div  class='ui-button'>
<a href='#' id='geolocate' >Find me</a>



<pre id='distance' class='ui-distance'>Click to place a marker</pre>

<script>
L.mapbox.accessToken = 'pk.eyJ1IjoiYWJ6YWwiLCJhIjoiY2llempiaW9oMWJvdXNnbTAxZnY4NTNvOSJ9.I0bW1wxrOYS2MPZD0FrTtA';
var map = L.mapbox.map('map', 'mapbox.streets')
    .setView([38.9, -77], 12);

// Start with a fixed marker.
var fixedMarker = L.marker(new L.LatLng(38.9131775, -77.032544), {
    icon: L.mapbox.marker.icon({
        'marker-color': 'ff8888'
    })
}).bindPopup('Mapbox DC').addTo(map);

// Store the fixedMarker coordinates in a variable.
var fc = fixedMarker.getLatLng();

// Create a featureLayer that will hold a marker and linestring.
var featureLayer = L.mapbox.featureLayer().addTo(map);

// When a user clicks on the map we want to
// create a new L.featureGroup that will contain a
// marker placed where the user selected the map and
// a linestring that draws itself between the fixedMarkers
// coordinates and the newly placed marker.
map.on('click', function(ev) {
    // ev.latlng gives us the coordinates of
    // the spot clicked on the map.
    var c = ev.latlng;

    var geojson = [
      {
        "type": "Feature",
        "geometry": {
          "type": "Point",
          "coordinates": [c.lng, c.lat]
        },
        "properties": {
          "marker-color": "#ff8888"
        }
      }, {
        "type": "Feature",
        "geometry": {
          "type": "LineString",
          "coordinates": [
            [fc.lng, fc.lat],
            [c.lng, c.lat]
          ]
        },
        "properties": {
          "stroke": "#000",
          "stroke-opacity": 0.5,
          "stroke-width": 4
        }
      }
    ];

    featureLayer.setGeoJSON(geojson);

    // Finally, print the distance between these two points
    // on the screen using distanceTo().
    var container = document.getElementById('distance');
    container.innerHTML = (fc.distanceTo(c)).toFixed(0) + 'm';
});


var geolocate = document.getElementById('geolocate');
if (!navigator.geolocation) {
    geolocate.innerHTML = 'Geolocation is not available';
} else {
    geolocate.onclick = function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
        map.locate();
    };
}

// Once we've got a position, zoom and center the map
// on it, and add a single marker.
map.on('locationfound', function(e) {
    map.fitBounds(e.bounds);

    myLayer.setGeoJSON({
        type: 'Feature',
        geometry: {
            type: 'Point',
            coordinates: [e.latlng.lng, e.latlng.lat]
        },
        properties: {
            'title': 'Here I am!',
            'marker-color': '#ff8888',
            'marker-symbol': 'star'
        }
    });

    // And hide the geolocation button
    geolocate.parentNode.removeChild(geolocate);



});
// If the user chooses not to allow their location
// to be shared, display an error message.
map.on('locationerror', function() {
    geolocate.innerHTML = 'Position could not be found';
});
</script>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Problem in short: first marker shows on 38.9131775, -77.032544, should be shown on users location.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, it's a little messy and not exactly what I believe you want, but could be altered to work as you want (I created a second featureLayer so that the original marker that denotes the found user location stays on the map - This way one has to click twice to measure two distances but at least the user gets to choose the starting point whereas the "found" starting point might not be the user's exact location.) I got rid of the fixedMarker that it starts with because we don't need it.
[The JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/damo_s/ejaemcnd/2/)

```
var map = L.mapbox.map('map', 'mapbox.streets')
    .setView([38.9, -77], 12);

// Create a featureLayer that will hold a marker and linestring.
var featureLayer = L.mapbox.featureLayer().addTo(map);
var secondFeatureLayer = L.mapbox.featureLayer().addTo(map);

// 1. Let's create a counter so that we can record the separate clicks
var counter = 0;

// 2. Let's use some variables outside the function scope
var c,
    c2,
    prevClick;

map.on('click', function(ev) {

    // 3. Check if we've yet to click once
    if (counter < 1) {

        // 4. assign current click coordinates to prevClick for later use
        prevClick = ev.latlng;

        // ev.latlng gives us the coordinates of
        // the spot clicked on the map.
        c = ev.latlng;

        counter++;
    } else {
        c = prevClick;
        counter = 0;
    }

    c2 = ev.latlng;

    var geojson = [
      {
        "type": "Feature",
        "geometry": {
          "type": "Point",
          "coordinates": [c.lng, c.lat]
        },
        "properties": {
          "marker-color": "#ff8888"
        }
      },
      {
        "type": "Feature",
        "geometry": {
          "type": "Point",
          "coordinates": [c2.lng, c2.lat]
        },
        "properties": {
          "marker-color": "#ff8888"
        }
      },{
        "type": "Feature",
        "geometry": {
          "type": "LineString",
          "coordinates": [
            [c.lng, c.lat],
            [c2.lng, c2.lat]
          ]
        },
        "properties": {
          "stroke": "#000",
          "stroke-opacity": 0.5,
          "stroke-width": 4
        }
      }
    ];

    secondFeatureLayer.setGeoJSON(geojson);

    // Finally, print the distance between these two points
    // on the screen using distanceTo().
    var container = document.getElementById('distance');
    container.innerHTML = (c2.distanceTo(c)).toFixed(0) + 'm';
});


var geolocate = document.getElementById('geolocate');
if (!navigator.geolocation) {
    geolocate.innerHTML = 'Geolocation is not available';
} else {
    geolocate.onclick = function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
        map.locate();
    };
}

// Once we've got a position, zoom and center the map
// on it, and add a single marker.
map.on('locationfound', function(e) {
    map.fitBounds(e.bounds);

    featureLayer.setGeoJSON({
        type: 'Feature',
        geometry: {
            type: 'Point',
            coordinates: [e.latlng.lng, e.latlng.lat]
        },
        properties: {
            'title': 'Here I am!',
            'marker-color': '#ff8888',
            'marker-symbol': 'star'
        }
    });

    // And hide the geolocation button
    geolocate.parentNode.removeChild(geolocate);



});
// If the user chooses not to allow their location
// to be shared, display an error message.
map.on('locationerror', function() {
    geolocate.innerHTML = 'Position could not be found';
});
```